# Is this javascript code malicious?

Tags: malware, javascript, backdoor, trojan

a friend visited this site:

- h-t-t-p-s://adidastore.buzz/adidass/tb.php?_t=1614958342

I malformed the url so no one accidently clicks on it
Below is the code the site is serving.
I don't know javascript and wanted to know from you, if the code looks malicious?

Thank you!

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.adidas.com/">
<meta property="og:title" content="Adidas Women's Day gift">
<meta property="og:image" content="/img/s/adidas.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="Adidas gives away 1 million pairs of shoes">
<title>Adidas Women's Day gift</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         function loadScript(url, callback){
            var script = document.createElement ("script")
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            if (script.readyState){
                script.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete"){
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        callback();
                    }
                };
            } else {
                script.onload = function(){
                    callback();
                };
            }
            script.src = url;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            loadScript('/j/og.js?_t='+ (new Date()).getTime(),function(){});
        },200);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Analysis of potential malware is not usually done here. But in short: the code you show is just downloading another URL and inserting it as script. So the full functionality is in the part not shown here and thus cannot be evaluated.

Comment: The code is not inherently malicious, it just loads another script. The `/j/og.js` script then redirects the browser to increasingly spammy sites. The user is tricked into sending Chinese spam messages via Whatsapp. I think the main goal is generating fraudulent views on ads.

Comment: ... and obtaining your phone number, as well as encouraging you to 'register an app' obtained via a `baidu.com` link .. whatever that means `:)`

Comment: *"I need to speak to the manager. I clicked register and shared with 20 friends, but it still won't give me my 'adidass' shoes."*